# API call to get a list of all transactions sent TO a specific address (not contract)?

Tags: transactions, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, etherscan

I have used the Etherscan API call "http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken" to get the list of all transactions **sent** by an account.
 However, I couldn't find one to get **received** transactions for an account.

Also, do these API calls return only the confirmed transcations? Or the pending ones too? If pending ones are also included, which of the following fields could be the status of the transaction:

```
blockHash
:
"0x6328ddeaef59621cdce67c801fea0e7d28815bf233b589c3c5c67896a47b1fd1"
blockNumber
:
"5842812"
confirmations
:
"111"
contractAddress
:
""
cumulativeGasUsed
:
"1687090"
from
:
"0x6a812b123eae1226d2426c6e8b7c0ffec550436a"
gas
:
"500000"
gasPrice
:
"1000000000"
gasUsed
:
"113191"
hash
:
"0xb17bfae7cb3048f41b0b463f8d5430cdfecc5303df9c619d5057d3b497f4268e"
input
:
"0xbe45fd62000000000000000000000000f4566cbdef5d1cfbce6ce0ab8fe62869a6050960000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001dcd65000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001094e7c38477db43f195b9016c97c0099000000000000000000000000000000000"
isError
:
"0"
nonce
:
"1323"
timeStamp
:
"1579782177"
to
:
"0x6fafb91cd63b4ec07e1d35a7bfd31df23e4a7aa2"
transactionIndex
:
"26"
txreceipt_status
:
"1"
value
:
"0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the url you included and this route seems to send all transactions - both to and from this account. ctr + f on the information below and you should find multiple transactions to this account as well.

`"to":"0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a"`

The documentation doesn't mention whether this will return transaction to or from this account. Per etherscan this api route will:

> Get a list of 'Normal' Transactions By Address
>   [Optional Parameters] startblock: starting blockNo to retrieve results, endblock: ending blockNo to retrieve results

[documentation](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts)